# when is the session data sent to server

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, servlets

```
HttpSession session=requestObj.getSession();
ArrayList<String> items=(ArrayList<String>)session.getAttribute("itemlist");
items.add(newitem);
```

In this code, why don't I need to set attribute

> setAttribute("itemlist",items)

back to session object eventhough I updated the data in this session.
And as far as I know, session data are stored in server. So, when these data are sent to server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is in Java, so I'm guessing it is running on the server already?

If you only have one server process, then you are directly modifying the same in-memory reference to the list which is already stored in the server session, so you will automatically see the changes.

However, you should actually call `setAttribute` any time you modify the state. If you are running in a cluster, or a cloud environment like Google App Engine which may be running multiple copies of your app, then this call will be used to propagate changes to the other processes.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do ----setAttribute("itemlist",items)---because you have a reference to itemlist which you have stored in items.

```
ArrayList<String> items=(ArrayList<String>)session.getAttribute("itemlist");
```

So any changes you make to "items" will be visible in the "itemlist" attribute.

The data are sent to the server when you submit the form.  A form could be submitted by clicking a submit button.